# Assert the URL or Navigate to it appropriately

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have one question - how to write a cucumber hook that asserts the web URL.

Example -

Let's say I am testing - https://www.usatoday.com/tech/

My Given is as follows -

```
Given I am on the "/tech/" page
```

I would like a method to add the base url (www.usatoday.com) + "/tech" and assert whether it is currently on that page

```
(driver.getURL() ==www.usatoday/tech/)
```

otherwise navigate to that page if I am not there.

Any Java pros that can help me with this? Many thanks my friends.

Comment: If you need solution with Python, I'll code it.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to stick to JAVA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Given("^I am on the \"([^\"]*)\" page$")
public void i_am_on_the_page(String arg) throws throwable{

String newBaseURL = getBaseURL() + arg;
String currentURL = driver.getCurrentURL();
try{
    Assert.assertEquals(newBaseURL, currentURL);
}
catch(Exception e){
    driver.get(newBaseURL);
}
```

}

I am assuming that you have a function - getBaseURL() that will provide you the base url.

Comment: I think I will make the baseURL a static String. should still work right?

Comment: Yes it should still work!